# Looking for data and models for events of Sun and Moon apparent motion in distant past?

Tags: the-sun, the-moon, celestial-mechanics, raw-data, apparent-motion

For the current Julian Era (from 1, 1, 4713 BCE to modern day), I am looking for a raw data tables or a model that allows to predict the following events related to apparent motion of Sun and Moon:

- Julian Days (with fractional part for UTC time) of Equinoxes and solstices within a given (Proleptic if needed) Julian or (Proleptic if needed) Gregorian year.
- Julian Days (with fractional part for UTC time) of all full moons/new moons within a given (Proleptic if needed) Julian or (Proleptic if needed) Gregorian year.
- Julian Days (with fractional part for UTC time) of all full lunar and solar eclipses and the coordinates where Sun-Moon/Moon where in zenith at that moment with given range of Julian day numbers.

I also would like to know if there any reliable model that allows to predict UTC times of sunrises/sunsets and moonrises/moonsets at given local geographical coordinates at given Julian Day Number or (Proleptic if needed) Gregorian/Julian calendar date.

References to raw data, useful software or even useful mathematical equations and Python modules would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can get Sun & Moon data from [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/). But you can't determ8ne UTC for times in the distant past or future, due to the irregularity in the Earth's rotation. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/40867/16685 & https://www.eclipsewise.com/help/uncertainty2004.html

Comment: I don't have any links to give, but you should be able to find a lot of study on solar eclipses, as historical records of them are often used to measure the irregularity in the Earth's rotation.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks! But generally, what we know, is good enough to get standard deviation of about an hour in Bronze Age and Antiquity, right? Its my primary interest.

Comment: As @PM2Ring cited, https://www.eclipsewise.com/help/uncertainty2004.html tells us that we'd be looking at standard deviations of ~4.5 hours at 4000 BCE.